# WriteValue For Characteristic method do not operate in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

My environment is `iPhone5(iOS7.0.2)` and `BLE` Tag.
I want to send data to `BLE` Tag. so I use this method:

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{

for(CBCharacteristic *c in [service characteristics])
{ 
    if([service isEqual:immediateAlertService] &&
       [[c UUID] isEqual:ProximityTag.alertLevelCharacteristicUUID])//"2A06"
    {  
        immediateAlertAlertLevelCharacteristic = c;
    }
}
```

...

```
      [self.peripheral writeValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&level length:1] forCharacteristic:immediateAlertAlertLevelCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

level is `0x70`. But sometimes writeValue method is not operated.

```
iPhone ==> data ==> tag (X)
tag    ==> data ==> iPhone(O)
```

What more can I take a look? `CBService`? `CBCharacteristic`?

Comment: What does this mean: "But sometimes writeValue method is not operated."?

Comment: If you try with `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`
, what do you get in the delegate method?

Comment: In CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse case, called didWriteValueForCharacteristic: method and with error, "Unlikely Error" is error message.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having a similar problem with a third party library.